# Loop for cropping, cloud masking Sentinel 2 L2A images

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, r, loop

I have 6 stacks Sentinel 2 images (10m resolution) that I want to crop to my AOI and cloud masking. After which I want to calculate NDVI in R. The stacks are 3 from different months of 2016 and 3 from 2018.

I have read my AOI and different bands to create a stack as shown below

```
forest_shp <- readOGR(dsn= ".", layer = "forest_fichtelgebirge1")
 
band2_20160708 <- raster("T32UQA_20160708T101032_B02_10m.jp2")  
band3_20160708 <- raster("T32UQA_20160708T101032_B03_10m.jp2")  
band4_20160708 <- raster("T32UQA_20160708T101032_B04_10m.jp2")  
band8_20160708 <- raster("T32UQA_20160708T101032_B08_10m.jp2")  
all_bands_20160708 <- stack (band2_20160708, band3_20160708, band4_20160708, band8_20160708)

#cropping/masking

new_all_bands_2016070 <- mask(crop(forest_shp), all_bands_20160708)
```

I seek any looping ideas?

Comment: Looks fine so far. What problem do you have?

Comment: @Micha, I would want to use a loop to crop to my Area of Interest and mask out clouds for the 6 stacks after which i can calculate the NDVI. So the loop is where i need your help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have put your stacks into a list `stacks_list`, looping in R can be done either using the regular `for` structure:

```
for (stk in stacks_list) {
# Calculate NDVI here
}
```

Or with lapply from the apply family:

```
ndvis = lapply(stacks_list, FUN = function(s) {
# Calculate NDVI for stack s here
})
```

I would add that if you convert the stacks to a `stars` object (or read the tiff files as stars objects from the beginning), then you can use the `st_apply()` function. THis works similarly to any of the *apply family with the addition that it implements parallel processing. So you first load the `parallel` packages and define your cluster (parallel::makeCluster()), then you call st_apply with the CLUSTER parameter for parallel processing.

```
clust = makeCluster(num_cores)
ndvis = st_apply(stars_list, 
      CLUSTER = clust,
      MARGIN = ..., # Fill in here
      FUN = function(s) {
      # Calculate NDVI on stars object here
      })
```

---

### Regarding cropping and masking

You will want something like this inside your looping structure (whichever approach you choose), where `s` is a single stack from the list of stacks `stacks_list`:

```
stk_cropped = mask(crop(s, forest_shp), forest_shp))
```

The `crop()` function returns a raster or rasterStack from `s` clipped to the extent of `forest_shp`. Then the `mask()` function sets all values outside of `forest_shp` to NULL. (In case the forest_shp is an irregular polygon)

HTH

Comment: Thanks but i still can't figure out how to crop in the loop before NDVI calculation

Comment: Thank you so much